# Qpid-Proton C++ connect or sender_open

Tags: qpid-proton

Some of the Qpid-Proton C++ examples calls connect from on_container_start and then open_sender/receiver from on_connection_open (helloworld) and others calls open_sender directly from on_container_start (simple_send). When would you use either approach ?